# Electron ShowInactive работает неверно

Tags: electron

Есть приложение на Electron. Необходимо развернуть его без фокуса по определенному событию.

Вызываю функцию `win.showInactive()` (в документации указано, что окно должно быть показано без фокуса на нем), но фокус устанавливается (сразу после вызова проверю есть ли фокус на окне с помощью `win.isFocused()` - возвращает `true`).

Как развернуть окно без фокуса?

---

Проблема наблюдается только на некоторых сборках Windows OS.